# I can't delete some files on my hard drive on ubuntu, says they don't exist, when they do

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, rm

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and a folder containing some images was saved on my PC, but when I tried to delete it, I get this error. Same on terminal.

[image: Error]

I noticed that the folder now has a thumbnail with a picture, but it's empty.

I have tried all the answers provided [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjYlKfgvMP7AhUoMVkFHaKgAv4QFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F623577%2Fno-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-remove-a-file-but-the-file-exists&usg=AOvVaw0t8-qJZ70zHNq4U1DVTYjQ), [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjYlKfgvMP7AhUoMVkFHaKgAv4QrAIoAHoECBwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F639627%2Ferror-removing-file-no-such-file-or-directory&usg=AOvVaw2CsFowuUw_EF8rh8JQXdkE), [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjYlKfgvMP7AhUoMVkFHaKgAv4QrAIoAXoECBwQAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F1008512%2Fhow-to-remove-file-directory-that-doesnt-exist&usg=AOvVaw1u5fXRzin1d-5GIkidiGEx). And many other places on the net

This is the output of `ls -la`

```
total 1444  
drwxrwxrwx 1 myUser myUSer    4096 Nov 22 18:57 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 myUser myUser       0 Nov 22 19:11 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myUser myUser 1474133 Dec 14  2021 Molly
```

Comment: All the answers? Can you confirm you tried to delete the folder with `sudo rm -r $foldername`? Did you rule out data corruption and how did you do that? Can you please provide the output of `ls -la`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that @Kamil, I'm not getting any response from Ask Ubuntu and see how fast I got a response here, I'd delete the other one.
And thanks @mashuptwice for your reply. Yes I have tried deleting with the `sudo rm -r` but I have checked for data corruption, how do I do that please?